# PermissionError while executing langchain with AzureOpenAI

Tags: azure, openai-api, langchain, azure-openai

I'm working with AzureOpenAI and langchain, constantly getting hit by `PermissionError`. This mostly could be due to the proxy, but can someone please check the code --

```
from langchain.llms import OpenAI, AzureOpenAI
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain.chains import LLMChain

llm = AzureOpenAI(openai_api_type="", openai_api_base="", deployment_name="", model_name="", openai_api_key="", openai_api_version="")

template = """"
Translate the following text from {source_lang} to {dest_lang}: {source_text}
"""

prompt_name = PromptTemplate(input_variables=["source_lang", "dest_lang", "source_text"], template=template)
chain = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=prompt_name)

chain.predict(source_lang="English", dest_lang="Spanish", source_text="How are you?")

chain(inputs={"source_lang": "English", "dest_lang": "Spanish", "source_text": "How are you"})
```

I also tried the additional `openai_proxy` parameter without much luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

your code runs smoothly! Below my llm config. Other variables are set with `.env`

```
llm=AzureChatOpenAI(
    deployment_name=AZURE_OPENAI_CHATGPT_DEPLOYMENT,
    temperature=0.0,
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation @DSgUY. It was also an issue with the firewall for me.